# Excel automatically applying styles to new data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm having a problem with Excel 2013.

I have a spreadsheet filled with names and related information for applicants.  When I contact the applicants, I highlight the cells (using the fill tool) so I know I've contacted them.

Here's the problem:  if I have all my names highlighted, and I add more data, then after I tab or enter out of that new cell, Excel automatically applies highlighting.  How can I get that to stop.

Summary of steps:

1. Work in spreadsheet containing rows of data that has been highlighted using the fill tool. (Let's say that data is in rows 2-10 with a header row).
2. Select cell A11.
3. Type in new data.
4. Hit "Tab" to move to the next cell.
5. **PROBLEM**: Excel automatically applies the fill to A11 (and to A12, A13, etc. as I tab out of them).

Is there a setting to change that will prevent this behavior?

Comment: I believe the option you want to turn off is in Excel Options (Alt+F, T) then choose Advanced from the left-hand side and finally uncheck *Extend data range formats and formulas* from the top *Editing options* section on the right.

Comment: I know it doesn't help directly with your question, but I like to add in a column and check off the rows completed. That why if I want to pivot the data I can easily filter by the ones completed or not.